# JavaScript Conditional expression without the use of Relational operator

Tags: javascript, web

Here is the prompt to start.

This is one way to code a conditional expression that tests whether a Boolean variable named isValid is true:

isValid == true

Code another way that doesnt require the use of a relational operator.

How do you evaluate a boolean to be true without a relational operator?  Has me a bit stuck

Comment: You can explicitely convert the value into a boolean: `Boolean(value)` or `!!value`, but you don't need that. `var isValid = 42; if(isValid) //...` also works perfectly. `false, null, undefined, 0, NaN, ""` are falsy, everything else is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts relational operators are :

- Greater than operator (`>`)
- Greater than or equal operator (`>=`)
- Less than operator (`<`)
- Less than or equal operator (`<=`)
- The equality operators (`==`/`===`) (and the inequality operators (`!==`)

One simple way to evaluate a variable as true or false based on it's "truthiness", without using relational operators, would be to use the `!`*(not)* operator twice

```
!!isValid
```

As "not thruthy" evaluates to `false`, and reverting it again as "not false" evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the expression by itself in any context that treats it as a boolean. For instance.

```
if (isValid) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
someVar = isValid ? "truevalue" : "falsevalue";
```